# android BroadcastReceiver not working as intended

Tags: java, android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

as far as I can tell this should work. Except it doesn't :-/

the idea is to extend all the Activity classes I use to include a BroadcastReceiver that pops up Toast Messages when I send them. The end game for this strategy is that async worker jobs can "discover for themselves" which is the "top most" form (if available) and then post messages to the uses via toast despite being part of a async event when **I DO NOT CHOOSE(*)** to pass the context as an argument.

> The problem: when I call doDemo() the fire event happenes (I get the
>   `log.d` from doDemo()) but the receive event never fires.

**(*)this is essential, it's the whole purpose**

```
public class ToastActivity extends Activity{
    private BroadcastReceiver ToastBroadCastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), intent.getAction() + " package: "+ intent.getPackage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("ToastBroadCastReceiver", "Broadcastreceiver: " + intent.getAction() + " package: "+ intent.getPackage() + " @" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
    };

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(ToastBroadCastReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.my.domain.BROADCAST"));
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(ToastBroadCastReceiver);
    }

    public void doDemo(){
        Log.d("ToastBroadCastReceiver", "doDemo Broadcast started" );
        Intent broadCastIntent = new Intent();
        broadCastIntent.setAction( "com.my.domain.BROADCAST");
        broadCastIntent.setPackage( "well hello test!" );        
        sendBroadcast(broadCastIntent);
        Log.d("ToastBroadCastReceiver", "doDemo Broadcast sent" );
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

After a long conversation with Ali this is what we came up with

```
public class ToastActivity extends Activity{
    private BroadcastReceiver ToastBroadCastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ) {

            if (intent.getAction().equals("TOASTMESSAGE")) {
                String message = "";
                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                if (extras != null)            {
                    message = extras.getString("message");
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("ToastBroadCastReceiver", "Broadcastreceiver: " + message + "|" + intent.getAction());
            }
        }
    };

    public void ToastRegister(){
        registerReceiver(ToastBroadCastReceiver, new IntentFilter("TOASTMESSAGE"));
    }

    public void ToastDeRegister(){
        try { 
            unregisterReceiver(ToastBroadCastReceiver);     
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ToastBroadCastReceiver", e.getMessage());
        }       
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ToastRegister();
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ToastRegister();
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        ToastDeRegister();
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        ToastDeRegister();
    }

    public void doDemo(){
        Log.d("ToastBroadCastReceiver", "doDemo Broadcast started" );

        Intent broadCastIntent = new Intent();
        broadCastIntent.setAction("TOASTMESSAGE");
        broadCastIntent.putExtra("message","hello test message!");
        sendBroadcast(broadCastIntent);

        Log.d("ToastBroadCastReceiver", "doDemo Broadcast sent" );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is the issue   `broadCastIntent.setPackage( "well hello test!" );`

edit your code like this

```
 broadCastIntent.setPackage( "com.my.domain.BROADCAST");
 broadCastIntent.setAction( "well hello test!" );
```

**also replace your this line**

```
 registerReceiver(ToastBroadCastReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.my.domain.BROADCAST"));
```

**with this**

```
 registerReceiver(ToastBroadCastReceiver, new IntentFilter("well hello test!"));
```

**in your onReceive do like this**

```
if (intent.getAction().equals("well hello test!")) {
                Update_chat_counter();
```

Comment: Indeed. The package needs to match your apps package or you can't receive the broadcast.

Comment: ok I am confused - how do I send a message "well hello test" and filter/package it correctly - I want to package/filter by com.my.domain.BROADCAST

Comment: I see but won't that simply filter (and *only* filter) for things with the `action` "well hello test!" what I want to do is listen for a message (EG: a string saying such things as "well hello test!")

Comment: I don't want to test for that text `well hello test!`... forget that text string it's just a string it's a `lorem ipsum` text could be anything it's the `toast` text . argh this is so confusing.. I want to be able to broadcastreceive a text string of whatever I choose (as an intent) and capture it via a listener :-( ....should I be using `setData`?

Comment: broadCastIntent.putExtra("key", "Value"); use this to put extra values if you want.

Comment: No, this is not work as you are thinking, because the action is a parameter string usually a `static final string` to pass multiple actions (**to take multiple action in onReceive() method**) and compare them in `onReceive()` method.

Comment: sorry mate the things you are suggesting you are obviously knowlegeable and on the right track but your answer as it stands doesn't fire anything onReceive

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20805/discussion-between-ali-imran-and-conners)